# Minha url do css não está funcionando no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Bom dia, estou aprendendo a usar o codeigniter, e estou com um problema no meu css... dentro da pasta applications eu criei uma outra pasta chamada layout, que dentro dele vai possuir um **header.php** e um **footer.php**. Quando eu acessar minha view eu chamo esse header e footer. Até ai ok!
na pasta applications também possui uma outra pasta chamada **assets** que dentro tem as seguintes pastas - **css** e **sass**.

No meu header, eu não estou conseguindo atingir o arquivo css... no meu autoload configurei a url, e na minha  **config.php** a url padrão está desta forma:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/project_system_hair/project/system_hair/';
```

e no meu **header.php** está assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('assets/css/teste.css')?>">
```

Ao executar e dando inspect de element o meu href fica desta forma...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8888/project_system_hair/project/system_hair/assets/css/teste.css">
```

Ou seja o caminho está certo... mas o console acusa um erro dizendo:

**GET http://localhost:8888/project_system_hair/project/system_hair/assets/css/teste.css net::ERR_ABORTED** e assim não consigo usar meu css.

OBS: o caminho da minha pasta dentro do notebook: **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_system_hair/project/system_hair/application/assets/css**

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado....

Comment: tente usar assim: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/teste.css"> o href nao use "http://localhost..."

Comment: Tenta usar caminho relativo em vez de absoluto.

Comment: Você está usando o arquivo .htaccess?

Comment: Sim... tem umas definicao de url base e RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT, L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o meu problema.... Pelo que estava vendo, mesmo se a minha url base estiver apontada para application, tera que por o resto do caminho.

A minha solução foi, por o application/ antes ficando desta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('application/assets/css/teste.css')?>">
```

Desta forma, o meu css esta "linkado" corretamente

Obrigado pessoal

Comment: Perigoso. Vc está expondo o _core_ do framework na web, o que não é muito favorável à segurança da sua aplicação... ([o desenvolvedor diz isso](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html#hide-your-files)). Observe as permissões com atenção, ou manipule os _.htaccess_.

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar sua pasta "layout" fora de "applications", a estrutura fica mais ou menos assim:

```
application
system
layout
    assets
       css
       sass
```